# I can't access the login interface after I installed r-base on debian9.11

Tags: r, debian

I want to configure the R language environment on my Debian9.11. 
After installed r-base by

```
apt-get install r-base
```

The installation is successful, and nothing is wrong.
and reboot, I can't access the login interface.
I have checked the logs in */var/log/messages*, here are the logs.

```
Oct 17 17:12:35 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303555.0900] policy: set 'iNENU-2G' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Oct 17 17:12:35 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303555.0903] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.3885] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <warn>  [1571303556.3887] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): hostname is not a FQDN, it will be ignored
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.3922] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): dhclient started with pid 749
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.3939] policy: set 'iNENU-2G' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.4527] dhcp6 (wlp2s0):   valid_lft 3600
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.4527] dhcp6 (wlp2s0):   preferred_lft 3600
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.4528] dhcp6 (wlp2s0):   address 2001:250:7401:5011::dff1
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.4528] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound, event ID="ae:6d:e6:dd|1571300873"
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.4850] dhcp6 (wlp2s0):   valid_lft 3600
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.4851] dhcp6 (wlp2s0):   preferred_lft 3600
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.4851] dhcp6 (wlp2s0):   address 2001:250:7401:5011::dff1
Oct 17 17:12:36 debian NetworkManager[388]: <info>  [1571303556.4851] dhcp6 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> bound, event ID="ae:6d:e6:dd|1571303556"
Oct 17 17:12:38 debian gnome-session[668]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Oct 17 17:12:38 debian gnome-session[668]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 256
Oct 17 17:12:38 debian gnome-session[668]: libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
Oct 17 17:12:38 debian gnome-session-c[767]: eglInitialize() failed
Oct 17 17:12:38 debian gnome-session[668]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 256
Oct 17 17:12:38 debian gnome-session[668]: gnome-session-binary[668]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: 子进程退出，代码 1
Oct 17 17:12:38 debian gnome-session-f[768]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x56517f3431d0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Oct 17 17:12:39 debian gnome-session-f[768]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x56517f3431d0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "20"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "23"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event6  - Video Bus: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "24"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "25"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event14 - A4Tech USB Mouse: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "26"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event8  - HP Wide Vision HD Camera: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "27"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "28"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "29"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event15 - HP WMI hotkeys: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (**) Option "fd" "30"
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) event4  - HP Wireless hotkeys: device removed
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:79
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:78
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Oct 17 17:12:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[658]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Oct 17 17:12:50 debian kernel: [   22.674542] random: crng init done
Oct 17 17:12:50 debian kernel: [   22.674546] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
Oct 17 17:14:27 debian kernel: [  119.954877] fuse init (API version 7.26)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't access the login interface`?

Comment: Looking at the `log` messages, ...`gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support ... eglInitialize() failed`. You can find a workaround if you google  the error. Not sure how this is related to installing `base-r` though?